# Email Script from server breaks Telerik RadGrid and RadDropDownList

Tags: javascript, email, radgrid, registerstartupscript

I am using a Rad grid to display some information where the grid checkboxes mark items and then using a RadDropDownList you can pick an action and press a button to do it. One of the items is to send an email to all the emails of the checked rows.

In the button click call back I enumerate the checked rows from the grid and put their emails together in a string buffer and then add script to execute the email on postback which bring up an email.

```html
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "mailto",
 "<script type = 'text/javascript'>parent.location='mailto:" + emailToBuffer.ToString() + "'</script>") ;
```

This results in the line

```html
<script type = 'text/javascript'>parent.location='mailto:dana@here.com; '</script>
```

to be put just in front of the all Telerik rad javascript code in the HTML.

Somehow this innocent little line of javascript causes the master checkbox on the RadGrid header line and the RadDropDownList to stop functioning completely. The dropdown list will not drop. The value parent.location is no where else in the view source html except my inserted email line.

I cannot figure out a solution to this problem, it feels like bug that Telerik objects would break so easily from a little self contained script. Perhaps there is another way to send email form the browser given from the server that would not break Telerik controls.

George

Comment: I don't think "parent" is a good word for a variable name. Can you try something different?

What exactly is the desired outcome of that line of code?

Comment: I just copied that email server code from from a search on how to send an email from the browser starting at the server. Not easy to find when almost every post is about sending email from the server instead.  I assumed parent is an HTML construct of some sort, can someone explain it's function?

Comment: If I try window.location.href instead of parent.location it still opens the email fine but the Telerik controls still fail.